# Automatically name a file based on cell data when saving a spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an .xltm template spreadsheet that I'm wondering if I can get a macro to populate the "save as" file name based on cell data, is this possible?

There are over 50 people who will have this spreadsheet, it's more of a form, and we are trying to figure out a way to keep the filenames uniform. I know there is the ThisWorkbook.BeforeSave, but I'm not really having any luck there. I just need it to make a file named something like `$A$1 R $B$1 T $B$3.xlsx`

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.

```
Sub SaveMyWorkbook()

    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strFolderPath as String

    strFolderPath = "C:\"

    strPath = strFolderPath & _
        Sheet1.Range("A1").Value & "R" & _
        Sheet1.Range("B1").Value & "T" & _
        Sheet1.Range("B3").Value & ".xlsx"

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strPath

End Sub
```

**EDIT**: After you clarified your question in your comment below, I can now safely say that the answer is: No, what you are asking is not possible.

What *is* possible is to put a big, fat command button on your sheet that says "Press me to save", and have that button call the above Sub. You can set a fixed folder, as in the example above, or have the user pick a folder using the `FileDialog` object (or the `GetSaveAsFilename` function, but then the user will be able to change the suggested filename, so less safe).

Comment: I know how to save the file in VBA, what I'm wanting is to autoname the file for when the end user clicks on Save or Save As, not just save a copy and still have that same file open.

Comment: Edited answer to address your clarification.