# Showing excel save as dialog box and prefill with cell reference

Tags: vba, excel

With no coding knowledge, I have attempted to use some code found here: [Automatically name a file based on cell data when saving a spreadsheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710757/automatically-name-a-file-based-on-cell-data-when-saving-a-spreadsheet). Thanks to [Jean-François Corbett](https://stackoverflow.com/users/119775/jean-fran%C3%A7ois-corbett)

I have adapted as follows to show the dialog box:

```
Sub SaveAsString()

Dim strPath As String
Dim strFolderPath As String

strFolderPath = "N:\PROJECTS\"

    strPath = strFolderPath & _
        Sheet1.Range("B2").Value & "_" & _
        Sheet1.Range("B6").Value & "_" & _
        Sheet1.Range("X1").Value & "-JS-1" & ".xlsm"

Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show strPath
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled

End Sub
```

I am opening an .xltm file, and attempting to save with the ability to select the subfolder of `N:\PROJECTS\` with the combination of cell references shown.

The dialog box appears fine, already showing `N:\PROJECTS`. However, it does not fill the file name, unless the file is first saved as a .xlsm.  It then always attempts to overwrite as well.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, utilizing a slightly different code technique.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SaveAsString()

    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strFolderPath As String

    ChDir "N:\PROJECTS\" 'set directory with this line

    With Sheet1

        strPath = .Range("B2").Value
        strPath = strPath & "_" & .Range("B6").Value
        strPath = strPath & "_" & .Range("X1").Value 
        strPath = strPath & "-JS-1.xlsm"

    End With

    Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show strPath 'load file name with this argument
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response.  This hasn't varied the result for me, also checking on another machine. I am wondering if the ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
line is really superfluous, but the file format part has to go somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

The main issue remaining was that opening from a template didn't automatically save as .xlsm. Apparently Application.Dialogs doesn't support file filters, so the problem is better solved with `GetSaveasFileName`.

Full code as follows:

```
Sub SaveAsString()

Dim strPath As String
Dim strFolderPath As String

strFolderPath = "N:\PROJECTS\"

     strPath = strFolderPath & _
        Sheet1.Range("B2").Value & "_" & _
        Sheet1.Range("B6").Value & "_" & _
        Sheet1.Range("X1").Value & "-JS-1" & ".xlsm"

fileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(strPath _
 , fileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsm), *.xlsm")

End Sub
```